# Doctrine 2 : OneToMany relation, Entity is not loaded

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony, lazy-loading

Here is my problem : I have the 3 entities Item, User and Link above (these classes also have the usual getters and setters).

```php
class User {

    //...

    /*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Link", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * 
     */
    protected $links;

    //...

}
```

```php
class Item {

    //...

    /*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Link", mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * 
     */
    protected $links;

    //...

}
```

```php
class Link {

    /**
     * @var datetime $time
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="links")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $item;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="links")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    //...

}
```

I did not use a ManyToMany relationship because of the $time property in the Link class.

When I create a Link, I do it this way :

```php
$link = getExistingLink($item, $user);

if (!$link) {
    $link = new Link();
    $link->setItem($item);
    $link->setUser($user);
}
$link->setTime(new \DateTime());
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($link);
$em->flush();
```

The data is written in the database, however when I call $user->getLinks(), it returns NULL. I event tried to do this :

```php
$user->addLink($link);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

But the link won't be loaded the next time the $user will be loaded.

Any idea why the Link entities are not loaded ?

Comment: I have never used the **@ORM\Id** annotation on a **ManyToOne** relationship. I think it's just for the table's ID, not for IDs in general. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Actually I've used @ORM\Id on those 2 properties because I want to make my primary key out of those 2 columns (like it would be done in a ManyToMany relationship).Nevertheless, I tried to set an single Id column and still got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Problem Solved.

The annotations starts with /* instead of /** in both User and Item classes.

Just a silly mistake ...